# async{} inside flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Can I use async{} inside kotlin flow .

**Scenario**: After the API call I get a list of 200 objects that I need to parse (convert to UIObject).
I am trying to process this list in parallel.
Below is the Pseudo code:

```
 fun getUIObjectListFlow():Flow<List<UIObject>> {
    flow<List<UIObject>> {
        while (stream.hasNext()) {
            val data = stream.getData() // reading from an input stream. Data comes in chunk

            val firstHalfDeffered = async(Dispatchers.IO) { /* process first half of the list that data obj contains*/ }
            val secondHalfDeffered = async(Dispatchers.IO) { /*process second half of the list that data obj contains */ }
            val processedList = firstHalfDeffered.await() + secondHalfDeffered.await() // just pseudo code

            emit(processedList)
        }
    }
}
```

As async{} requires Coroutine scope (eg: someScope.async{} ), how can I get a scope inside flow ? Is there any other approach to accomplish this ?

This function is in the repository and I am calling it from viewmodel.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use a flow in the first place if you only return a single item (which is a list)? If you planned to emit `UIObject` items asynchronously then your above code doesn't do this - it waits for all items and then emits all of them at once. Is the order of items important?

Comment: @broot : Got it.  In actual code I am reading a stream and emitting objects instead of List<UiObject>. I can see my sample code  is not as per my question. I will update the pseudo code.

Comment: In this case Joffrey's answer is the correct one. You just need to enclose flow body in a `coroutineScope { ... }`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Original answer to the initial question)

As @broot mentioned in the comments, you don't need a `Flow<T>` if what you want is to produce a single item (even if that single item is a collection).
In general, you'll simply want a `suspend` function (or a suspending piece of code in this case) instead of a function that returns a `Flow`.

Now, whether you keep your single-item flow or not, you can use the `coroutineScope { ... }` suspending function to define a local scope from which you can start coroutines. This function does a few things:

1. it provides a scope to start child coroutines
2. it suspends until all child coroutines are done
3. it returns a value based on the last expression in the block (the "return" value of the lambda)

Here is how it could look like:

```kotlin
val uiObjects = coroutineScope { //this: CoroutineScope
    val list = getDataFromServer()
            
    val firstHalf = async(Dispatchers.IO) { /*process first half of the list */ }
    val secondHalf = async(Dispatchers.IO) { /*process second half of the list */ }
            
    // the last expression from the block is what the uiObjects variable gets
    firstHalf.await() + secondHalf.await()
}
```

EDIT: given the question update, here is some updated code. You should still use `coroutineScope` to create a local scope for your short-lived coroutines:

```kotlin
fun getUIObjectListFlow(): Flow<List<UIObject>> = flow<List<UIObject>> {
    while (stream.hasNext()) {
        val data = stream.getData() // reading from an input stream. Data comes in chunk

        val processedList = coroutineScope {
            val firstHalfDeffered = async(Dispatchers.IO) { /* process first half of the list that data obj contains*/ }
            val secondHalfDeffered = async(Dispatchers.IO) { /*process second half of the list that data obj contains */ }
            firstHalfDeffered.await() + secondHalfDeffered.await() 
        }
        emit(processedList)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Joffery: Can you please take a look at my update pseudo code. The function is reading from a stream and then processing the data chunk and creating a UIObject list out of it and then emitting.

Comment: As I said, whether you keep a flow or not, you can do the same thing. You can use `coroutineScope` the same way.