How to suspend flow emit when collector is suspend?
If I call suspend function, the coroutine should be suspend. But how can I use this to suspend SharedFlow emit?
fun main()= runBlocking<Unit> {
    println("before, time is ${System.currentTimeMillis()/1000} s")
    delay5s()
    println("after, time is ${System.currentTimeMillis()/1000} s")

}
private suspend fun delay5s() {
    delay(5000)
}

the code will run correctly. But when I try this on SharedFlow.
fun main()= runBlocking<Unit> {
    val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(
        replay = 0,
        extraBufferCapacity = 0,
        onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.SUSPEND
    )
    launch {
        flow.collect {
            println("before on collect, time is ${System.currentTimeMillis()/1000} s")
            delay5s()
            println("after on collect, time is ${System.currentTimeMillis()/1000} s")
        }
    }
    launch {
        println("before emit, time is ${System.currentTimeMillis()/1000} s")
        flow.emit(1)
        println("after emit, time is ${System.currentTimeMillis()/1000} s")
    }

}

I Got
before emit, time is 1733335171 s
before on collect, time is 1733335171 s
after emit, time is 1733335171 s
after on collect, time is 1733335176 s

As you see, only collector was suspended. The "before emit" and "after emit" wan call almost at the same time.
I expect
before emit, time is 1733335171 s
before on collect, time is 1733335171 s
after on collect, time is 1733335176 s
after emit, time is 1733335176 s


https://stackoverflow.com/a/67888031/6892567 check this answer. It seemed to me that you are looking some kind of 'await' mechanism

You're wrong about a few things:

A suspend fun does not mean the coroutine becomes suspended.  It means that the coroutine may be suspended.  It doesn't have to be.
I assume you really meant that delay will suspend the courotine for the specified time.  That is true.

Your mistake is that you seem to think emit waits for all listeners to process the new value before it returns.  It doesn't.  Emit immediately returns on its coroutine. So which of the two lines prints first will be a race condition depending on the scheduling of the two coroutines.  If you absolutely need to wait for the event to be processed, you should be calling it as a suspend function rather than using a flow.  The emitter of a flow should have no knowledge of what or if anything is listening to the flow.

Thank you so much!
I see what you mean. I also understand under what circumstances the emit function will be suspended, that is, when back pressure occurs.
In fact, my purpose is to implement an observer model similar to SharedFlow, but the difference is that I hope to suspend on the producer caller before all consumers are completed, just like what I described above, there is a good Solution?

Main use case for flows is to observe producers by consumers, not the opposite. Especially in the case of hot flows (e.g. shared flow), producer is not running in the context of any consumer, it doesn't have a direct knowledge about consumers and consumers are entirely decoupled from each other as well. There are some exceptions from the above, e.g. back pressure and SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed, but the main concept still remains.
What would be your expected behavior if one consumer fails? Should it fail the producer and all other consumers? If yes, why one faulty service fails other, unrelated services? This is not the kind of behavior we expect from flows.
If we expect the producer to depend on consumers, we can use a classic observer pattern:
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val listeners = mutableListOf<suspend (Int) -> Unit>()

    // register consumers
    repeat(5) { consumerId ->
        listeners += {
            println("Consumer #$consumerId start consuming $it")
            delay(Random.nextInt(5).seconds)
            println("Consumer #$consumerId finished consuming $it")
        }
    }

    // run producer
    repeat(10) { item ->
        println("Producing $item")
        coroutineScope {
            listeners.forEach {
                launch { it(item) }
            }
        }
        println("Finished processing $item")
    }
}

Consumers register their suspendable callbacks to the producer. Then the producer calls consumers either sequentially or concurrently, waiting for all of them to finish before progressing to the next item.
To implement the above we don't need flows, which are much more complicated conceptually.

OK, I see. But before, I used flow to achieve local monitoring of updates to the State properties (through map), and it seems that this mode can no longer do so.
